# Query for Haversine formula in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, haversine

This query is working fine but I want to use the `MIN` function in this query, because I want only one station which has the least distance from the given current location.

How can I use `MIN` in this query?

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT fc_station_mst.station_name,fc_station_mst.station_id,fc_station_mst.lat, fc_station_mst.longitude,fc_station_mst.state,
          fc_station_param_dtl.fc_date,fc_station_param_dtl.param_value,fc_parameter_mst.param_name,fc_parameter_mst.param_unit, 

  6371*(2*atan2 (sqrt(sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2) * 
  sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2)+cos((3.14*fc_station_mst.lat)/180)*cos((3.14*23.07)/180) 
  * sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)* 
  sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)),(sqrt(1-(sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2)
  *sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2) +cos((3.14*fc_station_mst.lat)/180)* cos((3.14*23.07)/180)*
  sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)* sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)))))) as distance 

  FROM fc_station_mst, fc_station_param_dtl, fc_parameter_mst 

  where fc_station_param_dtl.param_id=fc_parameter_mst.param_id and
  fc_station_mst.station_id=fc_station_param_dtl.station_id  and  fc_station_param_dtl.param_id in(1,3,5,9)  and 
  fc_station_param_dtl.hourly_forecast='24' and fc_station_param_dtl.fc_date='22-JUL-2014'
) x

where   distance <= 15 ;
```

Comment: Where is the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: If there is no GROUP BY clause, the HAVING clause is applied to the entire result as a single group

Comment: Ok, but as I see, you use the `distance` field in the `HAVING`, but you can't use it here, because it is an alias of the `min` function, you have to either add top level `select` and use `where` clause or use the whole `min` function with sin, sqrt and etc in the `having` clause.

Comment: select *
from
(
  SELECT fc_station_mst.station_name,fc_station_mst.station_id,fc_station_mst.lat, fc_station_mst.longitude,fc_station_mst.state,
          fc_station_param_dtl.fc_date,fc_station_param_dtl.param_value,fc_parameter_mst.param_name,fc_parameter_mst.param_unit, 
    
  6371*(2*atan2 (sqrt(sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2) * 
  sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2)+cos((3.14*fc_station_mst.lat)/180)*cos((3.14*23.07)/180)

Comment: * sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)* 
  sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)),(sqrt(1-(sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2)
  *sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2) +cos((3.14*fc_station_mst.lat)/180)* cos((3.14*23.07)/180)*
  sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)* sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)))))) as distance 
  
  FROM fc_station_mst, fc_station_param_dtl, fc_parameter_mst

Comment: where fc_station_param_dtl.param_id=fc_parameter_mst.param_id and
  fc_station_mst.station_id=fc_station_param_dtl.station_id  and  fc_station_param_dtl.param_id in(1,3,5,9)  and 
  fc_station_param_dtl.hourly_forecast='24' and fc_station_param_dtl.fc_date='22-JUL-2014'
) x

where   distance <= 15 ;

Comment: I've edited my question...plz help me with this...

Comment: Doesn't your current solution work well? As I suggested you added top level select with the `where` clause.

Comment: current query is working well but I want only one station having min distance from current lat/long.In this query I got number of stations having distance less than 15km...

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to calculate all the distances you have, then you get the min distance and compare it value with all the distances. The station that has the exact value is your answer. Like this:

```
with t as (
    select * 
    from
    (
      SELECT 6371*(2*atan2 (sqrt(sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2) * 
              sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2)+cos((3.14*fc_station_mst.lat)/180)*cos((3.14*23.07)/180) 
              * sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)* 
              sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)),(sqrt(1-(sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2)
              *sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2) +cos((3.14*fc_station_mst.lat)/180)* cos((3.14*23.07)/180)*
              sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)* sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)))))) as distance 
      FROM fc_station_mst, fc_station_param_dtl, fc_parameter_mst 

      where fc_station_param_dtl.param_id=fc_parameter_mst.param_id and
      fc_station_mst.station_id=fc_station_param_dtl.station_id  and  fc_station_param_dtl.param_id in(1,3,5,9)  and 
      fc_station_param_dtl.hourly_forecast='24' and fc_station_param_dtl.fc_date='22-JUL-2014'
    ) 
)
select fc_station_mst.station_name,fc_station_mst.station_id,fc_station_mst.lat, fc_station_mst.longitude,fc_station_mst.state,
       fc_station_param_dtl.fc_date,fc_station_param_dtl.param_value,fc_parameter_mst.param_name,fc_parameter_mst.param_unit
  from fc_station_mst, fc_station_param_dtl, fc_parameter_mst
     , (
        select min(distance) distance
          from t
       ) t1
 where t1.distance = 6371*(2*atan2 (sqrt(sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2) * 
      sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2)+cos((3.14*fc_station_mst.lat)/180)*cos((3.14*23.07)/180) 
      * sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)* 
      sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)),(sqrt(1-(sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2)
      *sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.lat-23.07))/180)/2) +cos((3.14*fc_station_mst.lat)/180)* cos((3.14*23.07)/180)*
      sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2)* sin(((3.14*(fc_station_mst.longitude-72.71))/180)/2))))))
```

Comment: I've to first find distance from my current location to all the stations available in database and then find the min distance which is the nearest station from my current location.if this distance is <15 then that will be my answer

Comment: You didn't tell that in your answer, how could I guess it? Set up your mind and realize what you really want and then express it in your answer.

Comment: plz tell me how can I use MIN function in this query.i've use before the formula of haversine but it is giving me the error of "NOT A SINGLE-GROUP GROUP FUNCTION" and if I removed the other colums from select and keep only formula then it is giving me the distance...plz help me with this query...

Comment: If you looked at my answer carefully you would have seen: At first, I calculate distance for each station using your your formula (the `WITH` part) then I calculate the min distance among the values I calculated before and then using your formula again I look for the value that has the exact value as the value of the min value I calculated before.